# error al intentar instalar sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, terminal

Estoy intentando instalar LAMP en ubuntu para instalar Laravel con los siguientes comandos. Voy apenas en el segundo y cuando termina el segundo comando y intento instalar el LAMP tengo este error y no me permite instalar el servidor. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

```
root@me:~# sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
sudo: unable to resolve host me
```

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

[este es el tutorial que vi](https://richos.gitbooks.io/laravel-5/content/capitulos/chapter1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareciera que hay paquetes rotos, deberías probar con lo que te sugiere:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

o prueba con lo siguiente para resolver problemas de paquetes rotos:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

si todavía no se puede instalar Lamp prueba hacer la instalación simulada para ver que dependencias pueden estar incumplidas o que otros paquetes requiere para su correcta instalación con el siguiente comando (sin sudo).

```
apt-get -s install lamp-server^
```

Comment: obtengo esto:dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0018' near line 0:
 newline in field name '#padding'

Comment: intenta de nuevo con : sudo apt-get clean  luego sudo apt-get update y después vuelve a instalar el paquete en modo simulación con apt-get -s install lamp-server^ par ver si te arroja algun error antes de instalarlo